# Draw a rectangle above numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf

My objective is to represent two images [image]

and [image]

However I can't figure it out how to draw those rectangle with tikz. Here is my attempt

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em]
& & r_2 \arrow[d,dash]& & & & & & & & & & &\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you really want to use TikZ-CD for that? I believe just plain TikZ is better. Or maybe barplots with PGFPlots.

Answer (score 2):

With pure `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm and 0mm,
  start chain = c going right,
N/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, fill=#1, 
                        minimum height=1cm, minimum width=#2cm, 
                        outer sep=0, node contents,
                        on chain=c} 
                    ]
\node[N=green/3,above right=of {(0,0)}];
\node[N=red/1];
\node[N=blue/1];
\node[N=red/3];
%
\node[N=green/5, below right = of c-4.south east];
%
\node[N=orange/2, below right = 5mm and 0mm of c-5.south west];
\draw   (8,2.5) node[above] {$C_2$} -- ++ (0,-5.5);
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,14}
    \node[fill=white]   at (\i,0.5) {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect thank youso much